# Why isn't my variable being resolved in Java?

Tags: java, time, long-integer, bukkit

I am getting an error in Eclipse Java. My code is:

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
    long startTime;
    startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
} else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
    long endTime;
    endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
} else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("timer")) {
    long currentTime;
    long currentTimeForm;
    currentTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    currentTimeForm = currentTime - startTime;
}
```

I get the error `startTime cannot be resolved to a variable` when I save it. Is it possible that because it is separated into separate `if` statements, it does not get the variable? I am coding a Bukkit Minecraft plugin.

**How do I fix this error?**

Comment: How to fix depends on what you want to happen. Specifically what should your program do of `timer` is selected and no previous start time has been recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate the variables like so:

```
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
            long startTime=0;
            startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            long endTime=0;
            endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            
        } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("timer")) {
            long currentTime=0;
            long currentTimeForm=0;
            currentTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            currentTimeForm = currentTime - startTime;
        }
```

However, since you use the `startTime` in every case, you can just instantiate it outside of the if statements. You also never defined `endTime` in some cases, so here is the fully revised code.

```
        long currentTime=0;
        long endTime=0;
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
            startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            
        } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("timer")) {
            
            currentTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            currentTimeForm = currentTime - startTime;
        }
```

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: @MJ535 The old one, or the revised one?

Comment: The old one. I shall check the revised one now. Edit- It worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: @MJ535 If my answer answers your question, please consider accepting!

Answer (score 2):

declare the variables outside of the if cascade, or as members of a class; there is too little context in your question to be more precise

```
            long startTime;
            long endTime;
            long currentTime;
            long currentTimeForm;

            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("begin")) {
                startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                endTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            } else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("timer")) {
                currentTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                currentTimeForm = currentTime - startTime;
            }
```